# wordpress apply_filters

Tags: wordpress

I'm totally new to wordpress, so apologies for the poor explanation.

I'm trying to return a list of values of the array 'options' I know I could filter this info (and ADD to this array) by using add_filter with 'woocommerce_currencies' but how can I see the values already contained in the array?

Here is a snippet of code, it's from the woocommerce functions.php file - Basically.. I'm trying to echo the values in this options array.

```
'options' => array_unique(apply_filters('woocommerce_currencies', array( 
            'USD' => __( 'US Dollars (&#36;)', 'woocommerce' ),
            'EUR' => __( 'Euros (&euro;)', 'woocommerce' ),
            'GBP' => __( 'Pounds Sterling (&pound;)', 'woocommerce' ).....
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use the [`get_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) function to retrieve any named option from the database.

```
$values = get_option('woocommerce_curencies');
        foreach ( (array) $values as $option ) {
            print_r( $option );
        }
```

Comment: are you sure it is an option from the DB?

Comment: woocommerce_currencies, isn't an option in the database. They have woocommerce_currency, which is the selected currency your shop is set up in. What I want to do is return a list of the currencies from 'woocommerce_currencies'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currencies', function($currencies) {
    var_dump($currencies);
}, 10, 1 );
```

You can then modify `currencies` as you wish.

FYI, `10` is the priority within the `woocommerce_currencies` filter, and 1 is the number of parameters being passed by the filter.